# How to install AJAX on IIS 6.1

Tags: ajax, iis, iis-6, installation

I am a little out of my comfort zone on this... for years I have been running LAMP, but due to some odd little problems with some third party peripherals which will link to a web app I am building, I have found myself on Windows Web Server R2 running IIS 6.1. Here lies the problem. My application (developed on Linux) requires AJAX, and from what I can tell IIS does not support this. I have had a look around, and seen that there are lots and lots of people posting about this, but nobody seems to have a definitive answer (just a lot of links to outdated microsoft articles which have now vanished, or been moved...)

So, can someone help. How do I take my new box, and make it run AJAX? Also running Parallels Plesk if that offers an easier route...?

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: This is quite a confusing question. I have some questions: 1) If you are running Windows 2008 R2 you are running IIS 7.5, if you are running IIS 6.1, you're running on a Windows XP box. 2) AJAX is a programming technique, not a software package. If you're trying to install a software package, what is it? 3) What language are you programming in? PHP on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an easy enough process. Check out this site for a really nice walk through on it:

http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/installing-ajax-on-server

Hope this helps, cheers ;)

Edited: You may also find this useful: http://www.asp.net/ajax

Comment: Glad that helped, sometimes Windows IIS can be a daunting task.